# jedi-vim and vim-latex buffers problems?

Tags: plugin-vim-latex, plugin-jedi-vim

I have posted [an issue on github](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim/issues/440), but I am asking here too to see if someone can point me to an answer...

I have installed `jedi-vim` and I find it really nice to edit python files. But I came across a problem that I am unable to solve --- it makes editing of LaTeX files much more complex. The problem is the following. I have in my `.vimrc`:

```
Plug 'davidhalter/jedi-vim'
    autocmd FileType python setlocal completeopt-=preview
```

And when I edit a LaTeX file, the `$...$` marks that define an inline math disappears unless the line is under the cursor. It's like `gvim` trying to render the math formula... See:

Case 1, cursor in different line of the math formula (the cursor does not appear on screenshot, but believe me...)

[image: selection_036]

Case 2, few instant after, cursor in the same line:

[image: selection_037]

This make LaTeX files almost impossible to edit. Is there a way to restrict all of the `jedi-vim` effects to python buffers?

I checked that commenting out the plugin line will avoid the problem.

Does anyone know what's happening here?

### Update

it is a `conceallevel` problem. If I open a .tex file, I have the following after issuing `:verbose set conceallevel?`:

[image: set conceallevel verbose]

...which I really do not understand. I checked my `.vimrc` and I did not find anything that would justify the fact that the python sysntax is loaded for my `tex` buffers... but it is.

Really puzzled. Anyway, adding

```
autocmd FileType tex set  conceallevel=0
```

to my `.vimrc` solves (hide?) the problem.

Comment: Indeed, I find it *very* strange you associating the issue with jedi when not using that plugin doesn't make any difference. O.o

Comment: @muru --- I have no problem if I comment out the `Plug 'davidhalter/jedi-vim` line in `-vimrc` --- maybe I explained myself badly. Sorry...

Comment: Oh, I suppose then I misread: *I checked that commenting out the plugin will remove the problem. Even adding let g:jedi#auto_initialization = 0 will not solve the problem...* It seemed like the last clause applied to both sentences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with `jedi-vim`.  It has to do with `vim-latex` using the `conceal` feature of gVim, where some parts of text are replaced by (supposedly better) graphic representations when you aren't editing the corresponding lines.  In your case a superscript is replaced, but IIRC `vim-latex` does that with many other things, such as Greek letters in formulas, and various mathematical symbols.  The result depends a lot of the quality of the font you're using.

If you don't want that to happen you can set `conceallevel` to 0:

```
set conceallevel=0
```

(There might be a better / "right" way to tell `vim-latex` about that, but with SourceForge still down I can't check it right now).

But try it again later with other fonts, you might start to like it.

Useful references: `:help tex-conceal`, `:help conceallevel`, `:help concealcursor`.

Comment: Ok, that fixed. But I am sure it show on when `jedi-vim` is enabled; it probably set the `conceallevel` to something different from 0 at startuo. Thanks!

Comment: @Rmano Now that you mention it, yes, `jedi-vim` does set `conceallevel`, but only locally, for `python` buffers.  It should have nothing to do with `latex` buffers.

Comment: Yep, I see --- it's in `.../plugged/jedi-vim/after/python.vim`. I do not know why it is triggered for the latex files. Puzzled.

Comment: @Rmano It's a lot more likely that a `latex`-related plugin sets `conceallevel` than `jedi-vim`.  To find out where `conceallevel` has been set, open a `latex` file and run `:verbose set conceallevel?`.

Comment: I updated the question --- that file is actually read when I open a `.tex` buffer. Maybe some kind of sub-syntax editing for listing environment? No idea. Thanks anyway!

Comment: To find out where the problem __was__ you need to remove the `autocmd` so that the problem comes up again, __then__ open a `latex` file and run the `:verbose` thing again.  On a side note: use a `ftplugin` instead of an `autocmd`.  If you people knew how truly bad these things really are under the hood, you'd avoid them like the pest.

Comment: Yes, this is what I did. I think that the problem is that `vimtex` loads syntax highlighting for nested "listing" environment, see [here](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/master/after/syntax/tex.vim) from line 66 onward.

Comment: @Rmano So, where does `verbose` says `conceallevel` comes from?

Comment: @lcd047 it comes from jedi-vim's `after/syntax/python.vim` (which gets "forcefully" loaded for `.tex` buffers by the plugin.  I wonder if moving the `set conceallevel` out of the syntax file makes sense?  At least it would fix this issue probably.  Does it better fit into the `ftplugin`?

Comment: @Rmano Now this is something you could ask the `jedi-vim` guys: why does `after/syntax/python.vim` get run for `latex` files?

Comment: @lcd047 --- yep. Continuing in https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim/issues/440